# Net Standard Library - Add files to nuget content folder on 'dotnet pack'

Tags: nuget, .net-standard-2.0

Is there an automated way to include a config transform file in the nuget package that is created when using the dotnet pack command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding the xdt transform files in the class library project and then editing the csproj file to have this ItemGroup.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app.config.uninstall.xdt" />
    <Content Include="app.config.install.xdt" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When doing a dotnet pack this automatically adds them to the content folder of the nuget package.

Comment: This is adding the file to a "content" & "contentFiles\any\net40" folder for me. Not sure if that is a big deal but I wanted it just in the "content" folder to match the output I had when using a .nuspec file.

Comment: Adding <PackagePath>content\</PackagePath> as a node of the <Content> node fixed this.